# Power Pages Error on switching language - incorrectly urlencodes query string

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

I've set up a blank site in Power Pages with multiple languages (English, French German).

I also have a use case for providing a query string parameter (for example, id).

[image]

When using the standard language switcher, the entire query string is url encoded, including the question mark, which results in an ASP.NET error as shown in the image below. I have switched off custom errors in the portal site settings to show the error detail.

[image]

Not sure how long this has been happening, but it appears to be a new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a ticket with MS and they confirmed a recent change has resulted in this default behavior.

The good news is that it can be switched off with a portal site setting called Site/EnableLanguageDropUrlEncoding.

Set to false to switch off the encoding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes I just ran into this, and (for now) I implemented the following in our header template. It seems like the OOB language.url_substitution liquid object for some reason will encode the URL it accepts and doesnt decode upon return. So adding the script below and adjusting the href to # to pevent default behavior and allow JS to decode is my quick fix since I dont have visibility on the Power Pages server side implementation of url_substitution. I've tested this for performance (1000's of reloads / language picker per few ms) and no failures. Note that I'm still inspecting other PR's from my dev's over the last couple releases to see if this is not a result of another side effect. In any event this works 100% (in my set up).

**OOB language selection template (e.g language dropdown) **
**FROM:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  {% for language in page.languages %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ language.url_substitution }}" title="{{ language.name }}" data-code="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

TO:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      // Select all elements that need URL decoding.
      var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.language-link');
      links.forEach(function(link) {
        // Decode the URL part and set it back on the href attribute.
        link.href = decodeURIComponent(link.getAttribute('data-url'));
      });
    });
  </script>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  {% for language in page.languages %}
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-url=""/{{ language.url_substitution }}" title="{{ language.name }}" data-code="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**My custom template (i only support EN and FR languages so I dont have the drop down rendered, I just have an anchor to click / toggle between langauges**

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      // Select all elements that need URL decoding.
      var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.language-link');
      links.forEach(function(link) {
        // Decode the URL part and set it back on the href attribute.
        link.href = decodeURIComponent(link.getAttribute('data-url'));
      });
    });
  </script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div id="wb-bnr" class="container">

        <div class="row">
            
            <section id="wb-lng" class="">
                <h2 class="wb-inv">Language selection</h2>

                <ul class="list-inline mrgn-bttm-0 pull-right">
                {% if website.languages.size > 1 %}
                    {% for language in page.languages %}
                        {% if language.name != website.selected_language.name %}
                            <li>
                                <a class="language-link" style="color:white;" data-url="/{{ language.url_substitution }}"  href="#">{{ language.name }}</a>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

                </ul>
            </section>
    
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```